# Setting up DNS using BIND

Tags: domain-name-system, bind

i have troubles setting up my db files.
Please kindly point me in the right direction!

i need to define a nameserver that manage a domain example.org.au

then i need it to have two records. one called server which is the ip address of current machine

the other called www where www.example.org.au will be pointed to another ip address.

i cant seem to get my system to work.

This is my db.example.org.au file

```
example.org.au. IN SOA server.example.org.au. (
1;
3;
1h;
1w;
1h ) ;
;

;Host addresses
localhost.example.org.au IN A 127.0.0.1
www.example.org.au. IN A 192.168.1.200 ; another virtual machine
server.example.org.au IN A 192.168.1.199 ; current virtual machine
```

If possible Please correct my errors! thanks!

Any good guides out there?

Thanks in advance ! :)

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple errors in your zone file, such as a missing SOA RNAME (it comes between the MNAME and the opening parenthesis), and a missing dot at the end of the `localhost.example.org.au` label, which makes it stand for `localhost.example.org.au.example.org.au.` which is not what you meant. Same thing for `server`! The formatting of the SOA record is odd and the semicolons at the end of every line are confusing though syntactically correct. Next, you need to have NS records in your zone: at least one, but the administrator of parent domain (org.au.) probably wants you to use at least two. Finally, your choice of 3 for the refresh parameter is misguided. 43200 (commonly seen value) is much more reasonable.

You should start by copying a zone template from another source (Google for one, you'll find plenty) and edit it to suit your needs rather than writing one from scratch.